# keeping cursor shape unchanged

Tags: cocoa, cursor, appkit

in my cocoa application, I uss "[[NSCursor pointingHandCursor] set];"  in -mouseEnter, but cursor changes back when other views refresh. I hope cursor shape unchanged till I change it with code.

Comment: cursor = [[NSCursor alloc] initWithImage:[NSImage imageNamedByPPS:@"imageName"] hotSpot:[[NSCursor arrowCursor] hotSpot]]; 
- (void)resetCursorRects {
    [super resetCursorRects];
    [self addCursorRect:[self bounds] cursor:cursor]; 
}

I try code above, then succeed. I feel very happy. Share with you all.

Comment: add your code into answer.

Answer (score 0):

Implement [resetCursorRects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/resetCursorRects) and invoke [addCursorRect:cursor:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/addCursorRect%3acursor%3a)

resetCursorRects:

> Overridden by subclasses to define their default cursor rectangles.

addCursorRect:cursor:

> Establishes the cursor to be used when the mouse pointer lies within a
>   specified region.